# NgModel for a set of dynamic inputs

Tags: angularjs

**Problem**

my problem is that i can't assign ng-model to a set of inputs that
    are generated dynamically. in my previous questions,(solved already) i ask 
    on how to assign ng-model in "a"(meaning one) input that is dynamic. 
    (current problem)now, i have a set of inputs.

**What i've tried**

```
Set 1
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
Set 2
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="grades[$index]" >
... so on until the last set
```

[Check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UpbJKoJNMkQSgDLKl2vj?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ng-model within nested ng-repeat directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973985/using-ng-model-within-nested-ng-repeat-directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add addition property to your details array and assign it to the ng-model

```
"details": [{
    "answerid": "1",
    "questionid": "32",
    "question": "GFDS",
    "pi": "P1",
    "answer": "jyhgf",
    "val": ""
}]

  <li id="student-eval">Evaluation Score: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="answer.val" ></li>
```